# How do I fix the issue with TV tuner?

Tags: tv-antenna, television

I have an old CRT TV (Samsung) that has been running for several years with just a couple of repairs and with no major issues. Now, there is a problem with channel changing (when you change a channel it's number changes but the program won't change).

One TV mechanic said there is a problem with the tuner and the other said it is an IC. They said the tuner is not available in the market.

The solution everyone suggested is to use AV ports instead of RF (the first thing these mechanics suggests is to use a setup box). I can't use a setup box so I am looking for something like a converter.

I see some AV to RF converters are available in the market but could anybody tell me if there is a converter available for RF to AV? Are there any other solutions?

Also, do I get new problems if I continue using the TV set with this problem?

Comment: You would still need a tuner to select the channel from the RF (like turning the tuning dial on a radio to select a channel) and convert it to a signal for an AV port. These are commonly known as set-top boxes. Can the TV repair man replace the IC for less than the cost of a second-hand LCD TV? Depending on how the IC has failed, it *might* lead to future problems.

Comment: The cost of repairs plus the cost of powering the beastly old thing for some years to come make the venture rather uneconomical, in my book. A 32" LCD panel can be had for 99 bucks these days, and it'll use much less power.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry, there were some typos. I have edited the question now. We already have a LED but want to keep this CRT running.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks, we have a new LED in the living room and we want to keep this CRT TV running as a matter of sentiment as it never had major issues.

Comment: You might have better luck at http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You will need a set top box/tuner to receive TV OTA channels.